# Can't get ajaxful-rating-jquery to work with rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler, rating

I'm trying to use the rails3 branch of [ajaxful_rating_jquery](https://github.com/kamui/ajaxful_rating_jquery/tree/rails3) but I can't get past `bundle install`. This is my Gemfile:

```
gem 'ajaxful_rating_jquery', :git => "git://github.com/kamui/ajaxful_rating_jquery.git", :branch => 'rails3'
```

but `bundle install` gives me this error:

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'ajaxful_rating_jquery (>= 0)' in   
git://github.com/kamui/ajaxful_rating_jquery.git (at rails3).
Source does not contain any versions of 'ajaxful_rating_jquery (>= 0)'
```

I've had this problem before with a different gem and still don't know how to get around it.

Comment: No, I didn't. Editing question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the rails3 branch of the [original ajaxful_rating gem](https://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating/tree/rails3) works with either jQuery or Prototype.

This worked for me:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'ajaxful_rating', :git => 'git://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating.git', :branch => "rails3"


#config/routes.rb
resources :modelname do
  member do
    post :rate
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you have to create a __rate__ method in your User model?

Comment: No, for my use case I only needed to display prepopulated global ratings (not allow users to rate) but I think you would have to create a rate method in the controller of the item that's being rated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to retrieve the wrong gem.  Try:

```
gem 'ajaxful_rating', :git => "git://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating.git", :branch => 'rails3'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add rating capability for you rails 3.1 and higher application you can check the new gem called [letsrate](https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate).

Comment: Ajaxful rating gave me headaches but trying out this one ended my misery. Worked like a charm!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this easily right now due to proxy problems, but it looks to me as though the gemspec file is named wrongly in the Rails 3 branch.

It's called ajaxful_rating.gemspec and bundler will be looking for ajaxful_rating_jquery.gemspec.

Try forking the project and changing the gemspec name, perhaps?

Comment: It seems that it wasn't just the gemspec name, the contents were wrong too. I tried replacing it with the master branch version and the gem installs fine, but then I get this error: `undefined method 'ajaxful_rateable' for #<Class:0x00000102f85720>`

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, since I'm not able to test this at my current comp, but it *looks* like the require is different on the gem itself, than what you're pulling in. Give this a shot:

```
gem 'ajaxful_rating_jquery', 
  :git => "git://github.com/kamui/ajaxful_rating_jquery.git", 
  :branch => "rails3",
  :require => "ajaxful_rating"
```